# How can I send a multiple part message in soap spring-ws?

Tags: soap, spring-ws

I would like to use the spring framework and spring-ws to send / receive SOAP messages.  However, I don't see how to send messages with multiple parts.

```
<message name="getInput">
    <part name="authenticationKey" type="FPDS:userAuthenticationKeyType"/>
    <part name="awardID" type="FPDS:awardIDType"/>
</message>
```

http://www.fpds-ng.com/wiki/index.php/FPDS-NG

But I don't see a way in the api to do this, except to construct the whole multipart message myself, whereas, I have JAXB objects for the parts I would like to pass. 
Thanks,
Hank

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work by using CXF (using wsdl2java) instead of the default JAXB behavior of spring-ws.  CXF seems to have support for multi-part messages and CXF can be used with Spring WS (as well as Boot).

Comment: BTW, I found this answer useful for getting CXF and Spring Boot to work together:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27113468/cxf-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I didn't find a way to consume such a web service with spring-ws, but I did find this link to the relevant paragraph in the [WS-I Basic Profile spec](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1-2006-04-10.html#Bindings_and_Parts) which says that there can be at most one part in the body. So I plan to use this information to try and convince the person that created the service to change the service to only have one part in the body in order to comply with the WS-I Basic Profile spec, and thus improve the interoperability.

Another point which may help convince the service developers to change is the fact that trying to validate any of their sample request messages in SOAPUI actually gives an error because of the multiple parts in the WSDL: "line -1: DocLiteral message must contain 1 body part definition"

Bear in mind though that the WS-I Basic Profile spec is stricter than the WSDL schema, so while this service might violate the WS-I Basic Profile spec, it will probably still validate against the WSDL schema. However compliance to the WS-I Basic Profile spec is important because, [according to Wikepedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-I_Basic_Profile), many common WS tools and frameworks will only support services that fall within the WS-I Basic Profile spec.

Comment: So, I am incorrect about the multiple parts, there is only one part in and out, but in the JBoss WSDL editor, and in the Java code produced by wsconsume, it doesn't look this way at all:

    <portType name="AwardPortType">
      <operation name="get">
       <input message="FPDS:getInput"/>
       <output message="FPDS:getOutput"/>
      </operation> 

So I need to look into creating a different object than use by context ws-consume has made.