# CXF with Spring-Boot

Tags: cxf, jax-ws, spring-boot

I am attempting to get CXF and Sprint Boot to play nicely. I have a JAX-WS service endpoint called SubscriberApi. Looking at the spring-boot logs I see successful mapping:

```
Mapping servlet: 'CXFServlet' to [/api/*]
Setting the server's publish address to be /SubscriberApi
```

However, I cant seem to get the WSDL when hitting:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/SubscriberApi?wsdl
```

```java
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"})
public class CxfConfiguration  {
  @Bean
  public SubscriberApi subscriberApi() {
    return new SubscriberApi();
  }
  @Bean
  public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
    CXFServlet cxfServlet = new CXFServlet();

    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean =
        new ServletRegistrationBean(cxfServlet, "/api/*");
    servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return servletRegistrationBean;
  }
  @DependsOn("servletRegistrationBean")
  @Bean
  public Endpoint jaxwsEndpoint(SubscriberApi subscriberApi){
    javax.xml.ws.Endpoint jaxwsEndpoint =
        javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish("/SubscriberApi", subscriberApi);
      return jaxwsEndpoint;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your `jaxwsEndpoint` bean return an instance of `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl`, which extends `javax.xml.ws.Endpoint`:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@DependsOn("servletRegistrationBean")
@Bean
public Endpoint jaxwsEndpoint(){
   Bus bus = (Bus) applicationContext.getBean(Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID);
   EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, subscriberApi());
   endpoint.publish("/SubscriberApi");
   // also showing how to add interceptors
   endpoint.getServer().getEndpoint().getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
   endpoint.getServer().getEndpoint().getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());

   return endpoint;
}
```

The original post doesn't include a runnable example, but this should solve the issue.

A running example can be found here, with all the configuration linked together:
[Application.java](https://github.com/TheAndruu/spring-cxf/blob/master/ws-server/src/main/java/demo/spring/service/Application.java)

Answer (score 4):

**There's a much easier way** to get Spring Boot & Apache CXF running and providing a SOAP webservice based on your WSDL file: Just use the [cxf-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/codecentric/cxf-spring-boot-starter), which does everything for you. You only need to use the starter and it's [companion Maven plugin](https://github.com/codecentric/cxf-spring-boot-starter-maven-plugin) in your `pom.xml` like this (full example!):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.codecentric.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-boot-simple</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>cxf-boot-simple</name>
    <description>Demo project for using Spring Boot Starter CXF</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Place your **wsdl** somewhere inside `src/main/resources`, implement your endpoint class and **your done!**. That's really everything, no manual boilerplate coding (no `ServletRegistrationBean` etc.). This is just generated for you based on the WSDL - 100% contract first.

Here's also a fully comprehensible example project: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-samples/tree/master/cxf-boot-simple. And there's also a blog post series, which will introduce you to everything related to know: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/10/spring-boot-apache-cxf-spring-boot-starter/ Have fun!

Comment: What is the difference between apache's `cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws` and codecentric's `cxf-spring-boot-starter`?

Comment: The answer is in the very first paragraph of https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/10/spring-boot-apache-cxf-spring-boot-starter/ `But wait! Isn´t there an official Apache CXF spring-boot-starter?`. In short: The Apache starter only initializes parts of CXF, where the codecentric starter takes care of every needed component, initializes every boilerplate needed, generates the JAX-B class files automatically based on your WSDL (full contract first support), eases logging of SOAP messages and much more.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use autoconfiguration with a Spring Boot CXF starter by adding:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

See also: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/springboot.html

Comment: This is good one, but doesn't have support to bootstrapping spring inside cxf endpoint